# Merging dataframes with unhashable columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I want to merge two Pandas DataFrames. If the `item` code (e.g. A,B,C,D) are the same,
their attributes `a`, `b` must be the same, but `b` is a numpy array or a list that is
unhashable.

Foo:

```
item   a     b              
A      1     [2,0] 
B      1     [3,0]         
C      0     [4,0]
```

Bar:

```
item   a     b
A      1     [2,0]
D      0     [6,1]
```

This is what I want

```
code   a     b        Foo   Bar
A      1     [2,0]    1     1
B      1     [3,0]    1     0
C      0     [4,0]    1     0
D      0     [6,1]    0     1
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use `df.merge` and `df.fillna`:

```
out = foo.assign(Foo=1).merge(bar.assign(Bar=1), 'outer').fillna(0)
print(out)

  item  a       b  Foo  Bar
0    A  1  (2, 0)  1.0  1.0
1    B  1  (3, 0)  1.0  0.0
2    C  0  (4, 0)  1.0  0.0
3    D  0  (6, 1)  0.0  1.0
```

---

If `b` is a list type, you could convert it to a tuple first and then merge.

```
foo.b = foo.b.apply(tuple)
bar.b = bar.b.apply(tuple)
out = foo.assign(Foo=1).merge(bar.assign(Bar=1), 'outer').fillna(0)
out.b = out.b.apply(list)

print(out)

  item  a       b  Foo  Bar
0    A  1  [2, 0]  1.0  1.0
1    B  1  [3, 0]  1.0  0.0
2    C  0  [4, 0]  1.0  0.0
3    D  0  [6, 1]  0.0  1.0
```

Comment: when I merge, it gives me an error saying that b is a unhashable type numpy.ndarray

Comment: @niukasu Okay, so your question is about tuples. But you're working with numpy arrays :)

Comment: @niukasu Edited, the second solution should help.

Comment: Thx a lot. is there any way to get the desired dataframe without converting it to tuple.

Comment: @niukasu No. That's the way the API works as of now. There might be a solution without merge but I'm not aware of it.

Comment: OP' question == reason why I do not like merge :(

Answer (score 6):

Here is a way to merge without converting the unhashables to tuples.

Since the `item` code has a 1-to-1 correspondence with the values in the `a` and
`b` columns, it suffices to merge on `item` alone. Since the values in the `item` column are hashable, 
there is no problem merging:

```
import pandas as pd

foo = pd.DataFrame({'item': list('ABC'), 'a':[1,1,0], 'b':[[2,0], [3,0], [4,0]]})
bar = pd.DataFrame({'item': list('AD'), 'a':[1,0], 'b':[[2,0], [6,1]]})

result = pd.merge(foo.assign(Foo=1), bar.assign(Bar=1), on='item', how='outer',
                  suffixes=['', '_y'])
for col in ['a','b']:
    result[col].update(result[col+'_y'])

for col in ['Foo', 'Bar']:
    result[col] = result[col].fillna(0)
result = result.drop(['a_y', 'b_y'], axis=1)
print(result)
```

yields

```
     a       b item  Foo  Bar
0  1.0  [2, 0]    A  1.0  1.0
1  1.0  [3, 0]    B  1.0  0.0
2  0.0  [4, 0]    C  1.0  0.0
3  0.0  [6, 1]    D  0.0  1.0
```

There is a bit of touch-up work needed after the merge, however. Since we only
merge on `item`, `result` gets two columns of `a` and `b` -- the ones from `bar`
are called `a_y`, and `b_y`. The `update` method is used to fill in NaN values
from `a` with corresponding values from `a_y`, and then the same is also done
for `b`.

The clever idea to use `foo.assign(Foo=1), bar.assign(Bar=1)` to obtain the `Foo` and `Bar` columns was taken from [cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45991543/190597).

Comment: I knew there was a way. I didn't know it was as simple as a merge on `item`. Nice one.

Answer (score 3):

Or you can try this

```
foo.b = foo.b.apply(tuple)
bar.b = bar.b.apply(tuple)
df=pd.concat([foo,bar],axis=0).drop_duplicates()
df['foo']=df.isin(foo).a.astype(int)
df['bar']=df.isin(bar).a.astype(int)
df.b=df.b.apply(list)
df
Out[60]: 
   a       b item  foo  bar
0  1  [2, 0]    A    1    1
1  1  [3, 0]    B    1    0
2  0  [4, 0]    C    1    0
1  0  [6, 1]    D    0    1
```

Answer (score 2):

```
cols = ['a', 'b', 'item']
pd.concat([Foo, Bar], keys=['Foo', 'Bar']) \
    .assign(c=1).pipe(lambda d: d.assign(b=d.b.apply(tuple))) \
    .set_index(cols, append=True) \
    .c.unstack(0, fill_value=0).reset_index(cols) \
    .pipe(lambda d: d.assign(b=d.b.apply(list)))

   a       b item  Bar  Foo
0  1  [2, 0]    A    1    1
1  0  [6, 1]    D    1    0
1  1  [3, 0]    B    0    1
2  0  [4, 0]    C    0    1
```